org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Column 'account_id' is NOT NULL, however, a null value is being written into it
Using canal to synchronize Mysql data to Flink for processing, the following problem is prompted: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Column 'account_id' is NOT NULL, however, a null value is being written into it. You can set job configuration 'table.exec.sink.not-null-enforcer'='DROP' to such records silently.
This is my code:
import org.apache.flink.table.api.EnvironmentSettings;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.expressions.TimeIntervalUnit;
import static org.apache.flink.table.api.Expressions.*;

public class FlinkDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnvironmentSettings env = EnvironmentSettings.inStreamingMode();
        TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(env);
//        Configuration config = tEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration();
//        config.setString("table.exec.sink.not-null-enforcer", "drop");
        tEnv.executeSql(
                "create table transactions \n" +
                        "(\n" +
                        "account_id bigint,\n" +
                        "amount bigint,\n" +
                        "transaction_time timestamp(3),\n" +
                        "watermark for transaction_time as transaction_time - interval '5' second\n" +
                        ") with \n" +
                        "(\n" +
                        "'connector'='kafka',\n" +
                        "'topic'='transactions',\n" +
                        "'properties.bootstrap.servers'='hadoop102:9092',\n" +
                        "'scan.startup.mode'='latest-offset',\n" +
                        "'format'='json',\n" +
                        "'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',\n" +
                        "'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true'\n" +
                        ");"
        );
        tEnv.executeSql(
                "create table spend_report \n" +
                        "(\n" +
                        "account_id bigint,\n" +
                        "log_ts timestamp(3),\n" +
                        "amount bigint,\n" +
                        "primary key (account_id,log_ts) not enforced\n" +
                        ") with \n" +
                        "(\n" +
                        "'connector'='jdbc',\n" +
                        "'url'='jdbc:mysql://hadoop102:3306/flink_test',\n" +
                        "'table-name'='spend_report',\n" +
                        "'driver'='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',\n" +
                        "'username'='root',\n" +
                        "'password'='000000'\n" +
                        ");"
        );

        Table transactions = tEnv.from("transactions");
        report(transactions).executeInsert("spend_report");
    }

    public static Table report(Table transactions){
        return transactions.select(
                        $("account_id"),
                        $("transaction_time").floor(TimeIntervalUnit.HOUR).as("log_ts"),
                        $("amount"))
                .groupBy($("account_id"), $("log_ts"))
                .select(
                        $("account_id"),
                        $("log_ts"),
                        $("amount").sum().as("amount"));
    }
}

Of course, this is the data synchronized to Kafka：
{"data":[{"account_id":"1007","amount":"700","transaction_time":"2024-05-16 12:00:00.000"}],"database":"flink_test","es":1715763909000,"gtid":"","id":2,"isDdl":false,"mysqlType":{"account_id":"bigint","amount":"bigint","transaction_time":"timestamp(3)"},"old":null,"pkNames":null,"sql":"","sqlType":{"account_id":-5,"amount":-5,"transaction_time":93},"table":"transactions","ts":1715763909220,"type":"INSERT"}

How should this problem be solved?

anyone there? anyone there? Guys, look over here
